# How do I replace NULL in datediff with a text

Tags: sql, replace, null, datediff

I have a 2 different date columns and I'm using datediff to calculate the years of working. But there is nulls when the people is still working I wonder how can I replace it with a text 'Still Working'

So this is the table that I have

```
ID     DateofHire    DateofTermination
1      2011-07-05    NULL
2      2015-03-30    2016-06-16
3      2011-07-05    2012-09-24
4      2008-01-07    NULL
```

I have use the datediff formula and it shows like this :

```
DATEDIFF(year,DateofHire,DateofTermination) as 'Years of working'

ID    Years_of_Working
1     NULL
2     1
3     1
4     NULL
```

How can I replace the NULL after I wrote a datediff query i wanted to replace it with **'Still Working'**

The desired table would be like this:

```
ID       Years_of_Working
1        Still working
2        1
3        1
4        Still Working
```

Comment: Have you tried is_null() function of sql?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I'm not exactly sure where to put it in the query i'm new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will get `Years_of_Working` as Integer values. Replacing the attribute of the table with a different type is **inconsistent**.
I would just replace NULL values with 0, which would implicitly mean, that these people are still working.

So if the original table is called hire_info, then solution would look like this:

```
with diff_years as (
   select ID,DATEDIFF(year,DateofHire,DateofTermination) as 'Years of working'
   from hire_info
)
select ID, ISNULL(Years_of_Working,0) Years_of_Working
from diff_years
```

Comment: I have two different columns which is Date of hire and date of termination which i created a new columns : DATEDIFF(year,DateofHire,DateofTermination) as 'Years of working' and the value inside is NULL, from your solution i think i should have a exist columns called diff_years

Comment: Could you please write down the sql command how you generate the last table?

Comment: The last table is the desired table which is the table that i wanted the result to be but I can't figure out how to get it

Comment: Sorry I mean table before that.

Comment: DATEDIFF(year,DateofHire,DateofTermination) as 'Years of working' It is this query

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. You should change the table name to your own table name.

```
SELECT id, if(isnull(DateofTermination),"Still working",TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,DateofHire,DateofTermination)) as 'Years of working' from date_diff;
```